# Electron JS Error: Cannot create BrowserWindow before app is ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, electron

I am using **jQuery** within **electronJS** project.

I wrote simple code which opens a browsing window without any element

```
    const electron = require("electron");

    let { app, BrowserWindow } = electron;

    $(app).ready(function() {
      console.log("its work");
      new BrowserWindow({});
    });
```

and got an error:

> Error: Uncaught [Error: Cannot create BrowserWindow before app is ready]

in spite of the `new BrowserWindow({})` in the jQuery ready function.

Comment: Does it work if you replace `$(app).ready(function(){` with `app.on('ready', function(){`?

Comment: It works , can you explain why the JS function works and jQuery doesn't ?
the only difference i know between  them is the jQuery function doesn't wait for images loading to be ready while JS function wait for image loading

Comment: I don't have an exact explanation _(that's why I didn't post it as an answer)_, but I guess it has to do with the fact that [$.ready()](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) waits for the DOM to be ready. But `app` is not just a document. It's your whole Electron app. It's the main process. I suppose it needs other stuff to be ready... Again, those are just assumptions.

Comment: Thank you <3 ...